Discord.py modal form command has no response despite no errors in console
I want to make a command such that when I use it, a form would pop up for me to complete and my responses will be DMed to me and posted in another channel afterwards. Below is the code I used (I referred to multiple YouTube tutorials) in a group cog named modal; the names and numbers are altered slightly due to privacy and stuff.
I am able to run the bot normally without any errors, and all my other cogs and commands work as normal. However, when I use the modal form command, the bot does not respond at all, despite there bring no errors printed in the console.
The numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8 are printed in the console when starting up the bot (why does this happen???), and when I used the modal form command, only number 0 is printed in the console, which might mean that await interaction.response.send_modal(myModal()) is not working for some reason.

What I expected to happen

When I use the command, console prints 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 15 15 15 15 16 17 18 19 20
Discord shows me a modal form with 5 questions to complete (all required, paragraph, 1000-character limit), and an embed containing my responses is sent to a text channel and my DMs after I complete the modal form
The bot responds to the command with a message containing my username and user ID after I complete the modal form

What actually happened

When I start up the bot, console prints 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 (why???)
When I use the command, console prints 0 (why???)
The bot does not respond to the command (shows "The application did not respond" after a few seconds)


File: commands/slash_commands_modal.py
import discord
from discord import app_commands, ui
from discord.ext import commands
from misc.dicts import DICT

class myModal(ui.Modal, title="Why not working"):
   print("2") # debug no.2
   a1 = ui.TextInput(
      label=DICT["a"][0],
      placeholder=DICT["ax"][0],
      style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph,
      max_length=1000,
      required=True
      )
   print("3") # debug no.3
   a2 = ui.TextInput(
      label=DICT["a"][1],
      placeholder=DICT["ax"][1],
      style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph,
      max_length=1000,
      required=True
      )
   print("4") # debug no.4
   a3 = ui.TextInput(
      label=DICT["a"][2],
      placeholder=DICT["ax"][2],
      style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph,
      max_length=1000,
      required=True
      )
   print("5") # debug no.5
   a4 = ui.TextInput(
      label=DICT["a"][3],
      placeholder=DICT["ax"][3],
      style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph,
      max_length=1000,
      required=True
      )
   print("6") # debug no.6
   a5 = ui.TextInput(
      label=DICT["a"][4],
      placeholder=DICT["ax"][4],
      style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph,
      max_length=1000,
      required=True
      )
   print("7") # debug no.7
   a = [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5]
   print("8") # debug no.8
   async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
      print("9") # debug no.9
      channel = self.bot.get_channel(9999999999999999999)
      print("10") # debug no.10
      d = f"- Username: **{interaction.user.name}**\n- User ID: ||**`{interaction.user.id}`**||"
      print("11") # debug no.11
      e = discord.Embed(title=f"Form", description=d, colour=0xe74c3c)
      print("12") # debug no.12
      e.set_footer(text="Form Response")
      print("13") # debug no.13
      q = DICT["a"]
      print("14") # debug no.14
      for i, j in zip(q, self.a):
         e.add_field(name=i, value=j, inline=False)
         print("15") # debug no.15
      await channel.send(embed=e)
      print("16") # debug no.16
      await interaction.response.send_message(f"- Username: **{interaction.user.name}**\n- User ID: ||**`{interaction.user.id}`**||\n\nThe form is done yay", ephemeral=True)
      print("17") # debug no.17
      user = self.bot.get_user(interaction.user.id)
      print("18") # debug no.18
      await user.create_dm()
      print("19") # debug no.19
      await user.dm_channel.send(embed=e)
      print("20") # debug no.20

class SlashCmd_Modal(commands.GroupCog, group_name="modal"):
  def __init__(self, bot):
      self.bot = bot

  @app_commands.command(name="form", description="a description")
  @app_commands.describe(role="another description")
  @app_commands.choices(role = [
    app_commands.Choice(name="A", value="a"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="B", value="b"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="C", value="c"),
    app_commands.Choice(name="D", value="d")
  ])
  async def form(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, role: str):
    if role == "a":
       print("0") # debug no.0
       await interaction.response.send_modal(myModal())
       print("1") # debug no.1
    elif role == "b":
       ... # similar kind of form but different class
    elif role == "c":
       ... # similar kind of form but different class
    elif role == "d":
       ... # similar kind of form but different class

async def setup(bot):
  await bot.add_cog(SlashCmd_Modal(bot))

File: misc/dict.py
DICT = {
"a": [ # questions
    "Q1",
    "Q2",
    "Q3",
    "Q4",
    "Q5"
],
"ax": [ # placeholders
    "P1",
    "P2",
    "P3",
    "P4",
    "P5"
]
}


EDIT I tried to start from scratch and make a test modal with three questions, as shown in the code below. This time the bot command and modal works as intended. However, the console does not print as I expected (I expected the console to print the responses to the questions while the console printed the questions themselves).
Note that unlike the code above, I did not alter the code below at all.
What I expected to happen:

When I use the command, console prints mt0 mt1 mt2 mt3 mt4 mt5 mt6 mt7 [<response to q1>, <response to q2>, <response to q3>] mt8 mt9

What actually happened:

When I start up the bot, console prints mt2 mt3 mt4 mt5 (why???)
When I use the command, console prints mt0 mt1 mt6 mt7 [<details of q1>, <details of q2>, <details of q3>] mt8 mt9

Where did I go wrong before? Why does the console print those upon bot startup? And how can I make the console print my responses instead of the questions?

Console (when I used the command)
mt0
mt1
mt6
mt7
[<TextInput label='first question' placeholder=None required=True>, <TextInput label='second question' placeholder='a placeholder' required=True>, <TextInput label='third question' placeholder='another placeholder' required=True>]
mt8
mt9

File: commands/slash_commands_modaltest.py
import discord
from discord import app_commands, ui
from discord.ext import commands

class myModal(ui.Modal, title="test modal"):
   print("mt2")
   a1 = ui.TextInput(
      label="first question"
      )
   print("mt3")
   a2 = ui.TextInput(
      label="second question",
      placeholder="a placeholder"
      )
   print("mt4")
   a3 = ui.TextInput(
      label="third question",
      placeholder="another placeholder",
      style=discord.TextStyle.paragraph,
      max_length=1000,
      required=True
   )
   print("mt5")
   async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
      print("mt6")
      a = [self.a1, self.a2, self.a3]
      print("mt7")
      print(a)
      print("mt8")
      await interaction.response.send_message("modal successful")
      print("mt9")

class SlashCmd_Modal(commands.GroupCog, group_name="modal"):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @app_commands.command(name="test", description="A Discord modal test command.")
  async def application(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    print("mt0")
    await interaction.response.send_modal(myModal())
    print("mt1")

async def setup(bot):
  await bot.add_cog(SlashCmd_Modal(bot))


as I know discord may catch errors (to keep running server even if there are mistakes) and hide them. It may need to change settings in logging to see errors. Setting Up Logging


When I start up the bot, console prints mt2 mt3 mt4 mt5 (why???)

All these prints are directly in your class, and will be called when you launch your program. mt0, mt1, and mt6 and above are contained within functions, and will therefore only execute when these functions are called.
Concerning your responses, you are printing directly your TextInputs, you should instead print the value for each of them :
print([t.value for t in a])

If you are struggling with modals, here is a good example of a basic modal. It also implements on_error, which you can use to solve your initial problem with your 5 questions modal.

implemented on_error and try...except; turns out the modals werent working cuz of bad request labels max 45 characters and placeholders max 100 characters; i checked the dictionary i used again and found out that i exceeded this limit by like 3 times lol
